# Affecting Specific Records Within Crystal Report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a Function that, when activated, iterates through the Crystal Report it is attached to, copies it to a pdf, then mails *the entirety of it* to a client *once per identifying field*.

They want to receive a pdf of records grouped by ID, for each ID in the Report, omitting some of a specific ID. I have no idea how to break the Report down into smaller Reports, though, or even where to begin if that's possible in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I am Creating Each Pdf for individual user and saving to my Google Driver also emailing using SendGrip Api.

- **I have used this code inside page.Aspx -> aspx.cs file.**

  ```
      //0. Here i am getting list users as an Object:
      OpsManagementController OM = new OpsManagementController();

      //1. Getting Users List:
      var result = OM.UsersGetforInvoice();

      //2. Creating folder for Invoices:
      string folderName = @"D:\Google Drive\MonthlyInvoices";
      string fileName = ("Invoices_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").ToString());
      string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);
      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

      string folderNameEmail = @"D:\Google Drive\MonthlyInvoices\Email";
      string fileNameEmail = ("Invoices_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").ToString());
      string pathStringEmail = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderNameEmail, fileNameEmail);
      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathStringEmail);


      //3. Generating invoices by user name:

      for (int i = 0; i < result.UserDetail.Count; i++)
      {
          var userId = result.UserDetail[i].UserID;
          var userEmail = result.UserDetail[i].Email;
          var userName = result.UserDetail[i].FullName;
          userName = userName.Replace(@"C\O", "CO");
          userName = userName.Replace(@"C/O", "CO");

          // Directories for reports:
          var invoicePath = "D:/Google Drive/MonthlyInvoices/" + fileName + "/" + userId + " " + userName + ".pdf";
          var invoicePath_email = "D:/Google Drive/MonthlyInvoices/Email/" + fileNameEmail + "/" + userId + " " + userName + ".pdf";

          report2.SetParameterValue("UserID", result.UserDetail[i].UserID);

          report2.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, invoicePath);

           // using sendgrip Api :
          EmailUtils.SendEmail_Att(
                              new string[] { userEmail }, //TO : userEmail
                              new string[] { "email@gmail.com" }, //
                              invoiceSubject,
                              invoiceBody,
                              invoicePath_email
                              );
      }
  ```